# Parse Android: delete object from array

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm writing an app where you can upvote/downvote a post, like Reddit for example.
When a user has downvoted a post, but clicks upvote on the same post, I need to remove the previous downvote.

So: User downvotes post, decides to upvote >> downvote deleted, upvote created on the post.

Post has an array with upvote & downvote objects.
When I remove the actual downvote object, the object is still there in the array (which is normal).
I try to remove the downvote from the array in the Post class like this:

```
//Delete the object from the array
            Logger.d("downvotes before " + post.getDownvotes().size());
            post.getDownvotes().remove(downvoteToDelete);
            Logger.d("downvotes after " + post.getDownvotes().size());

            post.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        Logger.d("deleted the downvote from the post object");
                    } else {
                        Logger.d("error " + e.getCode());
                    }
                }
            });
```

The logcat prints:

```
- downvotes before 1
- downvotes after 0
- deleted the downvote from the post object
```

but the array is the same... **How do I properly delete an object from an array?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to set the new array (after the element deletion) to the post object.

extract the array to local variable, Then remove the object from the array and then setDownvotes with the local variable and then perform the post.saveInBackground().

```
        localDownVotes = post.getDownvotes();
        localDownVotes.remove(downvoteToDelete);
        post.setDownvotes(localDownVotes);

        post.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    Logger.d("deleted the downvote from the post object");
                } else {
                    Logger.d("error " + e.getCode());
                }
            }
        });
```